# Como enviar y recibir comandos via telnet en una aplicacion java?

Tags: java, telnet

estoy tratando de realizar un programa para la muestra de parametros metereologicos que vienen desde otro equipo remoto. Hasta los momentos con el codigo que tengo implementado solo tengo la conexion con el equipo remoto pero no logro obtener la forma de enviarle comandos y de recibir el mismo, quien pueda ayudarme se le agradeceria. Cabe acotar que soy nuevo en esto de la programacion pero es sumamamente necesario realizar esto debido a que mi trabajo de grado depende de esta conexion para poder hacer el culmino de la aplicacion que debo diseñar para complementar el mismo. el codigo utilizado es el siguiente.

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import 
   org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
  //import java.io.PrintStream;

 public class AutomatedTelnetClient {
private TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
private InputStream in;
private PrintStream out;
private String prompt = "#";

public AutomatedTelnetClient(String server, String user, String password) {
    try {
        // Connect to the specified server
        telnet.connect(server, 23);

        // Get input and output stream references
        in = telnet.getInputStream();
        out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());

        // Log the user on
        readUntil("login: ");
        write(user);
        readUntil("Password: ");
        write(password);

        // Advance to a prompt
        readUntil(prompt + " ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void su(String password) {
    try {
        write("su");
        readUntil("Password: ");
        write(password);
        prompt = "#";
        readUntil(prompt + " ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String readUntil(String pattern) {
    try {
        char lastChar = pattern.charAt(pattern.length() - 1);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        boolean found = false;
        char ch = (char) in.read();
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(ch);
            sb.append(ch);
            if (ch == lastChar) {
                if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) {
                    return sb.toString();
                }
            }
            ch = (char) in.read();
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void write(String value) {
    try {
        out.println(value);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String sendCommand(String command) {
    try {
        write(command);
        return readUntil(prompt + "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void disconnect() {
    try {
        telnet.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient(
                "127.0.0.1", "userId", "Password");
        System.out.println("Got Connection...");
        telnet.sendCommand("ps -ef ");
        System.out.println("run command");
        telnet.sendCommand("ls ");
        System.out.println("run command 2");
        telnet.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Algun error que te este dando?

Comment: Buenos dias Raul, Bueno ya por fin tengo la conexion establecida ya pude descifrar el codigo y vi como era su comportamiento, ando en la fase de querer saber cual es el tipo de codificacion utilizada en la resuesta. Debido a que luego de obtener esta respuesta debo sacar o realizar mejor dicho un subString para ir desglosando la informacion en los distintos parametros metereologicos que querre adicionar a la base de datos, debido a que cada 60 seg debo establecer esta conexion telnet y solicitar los datos el tema esta en que no se si se trata del tipo ASCII o si por otro lado se trata de UTF-8

Comment: me pareciera que fuera ASCII debido aque estuve indagando en la web y consegui que el numero correspondiente al caracter son bastante parecidos a los arrojados por el sistema mas sin embargo hay algunos caracteres que no coinciden